# Are Multiple Random Intercepts Redundant in This Mixed Model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm curious what is going on behind the scenes when I have two mixed models:

```
s.mod1 = lmer(score ~ (1 + age | state), data=dfScore)
```

and

```
s.mod2 = lmer(score ~ (1 + age | state) + (1 | state), data=dfScore)
```

This second model does not make intuitive sense to me.  I would think that the addition of (1 | state) as a separate random intercept for state would be redundant.  However, I get a slightly better prediction for my test set from this model as well as a warning:

```
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

The fixed intercept is the same  (actually different by .0000001, not material).  The REML criterions at convergence are identical.  The scaled residuals are identical.  When I do a coef(s.mod1) and coef(s.mod2), I don't get two separate sets of intercepts for s.mod2, however the resulting age coefficients and intercepts for each state are very similar but not identical.  Do these models end up evaluating the same equation w/ differing results:

```
SCORE = INTERCEPT_GLOBAL + (INTERCEPT_STATE + AGE_COEF_STATE x age) + ERROR
```

Comment: This is possibly better asked on cross-validated. But I think the issue is that you're mixing things, and that's likely why the warning is generated. `(1 | state)` models it as a random intercept with a fixed mean, while `(1 + age | state)` models it as a random intercept and random slope. So in essence in `s.mod2` you are saying, `age` has random slopes for each `state`, while also having one slope for all states. You may want `(0 + age | state) + (1 | state)`, I'm not sure what your exact question for your analysis is.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward I'm just trying to understand what is going on behind the scenes and why the two models get different results.  I think the second (1 | state) is redundant, yet the results differ.

Comment: `s.mod2` does not make sense because (1|state) is included into it twice.

Comment: @amoeba I agree.  What makes the model return slightly different random slopes for age and random intercepts for state?  I thought maybe the model would create two "offsetting" random intercepts for state and therefore have trouble with infinite possibilities, but it seems to find a very close answer to model 1 and only returns 1 set of random intercepts for state.

Comment: I would think that `lmer` detects that random intercept is included twice and drops one of them. But I am not sure what it does internally in this case. Anyway, you should not use `s.mod2`, as the Warning tells you.